# regex to replace all occurrences after a match

Tags: java, regex

I am looking to remove the ***upper*** keyword after the ORDER BY in the following statement:

```
select upper(a.col1), b.col1
from a join
     b
     on a.q = b.q
order by upper(a.col1), upper(b.col1)
```

desired output:

```
select upper(a.col1), b.col1
from a join
     b
     on a.q = b.q
order by (a.col1), (b.col1)
```

I have tried lookbehind or the simple https://regex101.com/r/sfhDpt/1 but it only matches one instance.

The context is SQL translation - the original SQL works in MSSQL or Oracle but not in DB2 or H2 so I need an easy way (read, regex) to transform when needed.

Can this even be done with one single regex ?

Comment: Just for my understanding, why would you want to remove the usage of upper function in the order-by clause only ?

Comment: Both your queries should work in any database.  Are you sure you don't have a `group by` in the query?  Or, perhaps, sample data and desired results would better explain what you really want to do.

Comment: Is there a reasonable maximum number of occurrences of the usage of `upper()` in an `order by`? If so, what is that limit?

Comment: @RavindraHV - as I mentioned, DB2 and H2 do not allow the use of upper (or other scalar function) if it is not part of the selection. In my example, b.col1 is the issue. I know the SQL is ill-formed but that's how the application was written.

Comment: @Bohemian - I have traced back 3 occurences max in the SQL passed by the legacy application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a regex should do that (`perl` syntax):

```
s/(order by)((.*?)upper)*/$1$3/s
```

It takes advantage from repeated matching by the third group. [test](https://regex101.com/r/sfhDpt/2)

Edit: Unfortunately the above does not work for more than 2 `upper` strings, because the repeated matching group captures only last occurrence. To catch all of them in `perl` one may write:

```
s/(order by)(?{$x=""})((.*?)(?{$x.=$3})upper)*/$1$x/s
```

which captures all $3 occurrences in $x variable. This uses `perl` code executions in regexp and will not work in `pcre` (although `callouts` may be used there to call an external function to do a similar trick). [test](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_perl_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMS1phelAtMUszbEU)

Of course the repetition may also be unrolled manually like that:

```
s/(order by)((.*?)upper)?((.*?)upper)?((.*?)upper)?((.*?)upper)?/$1$3$5$7$9/s
```

but in such a case `((.*?)upper)?` must be repeated (along with replacement variables) as many times as `upper` can happen in the source string. [test](https://regex101.com/r/sfhDpt/3)

Comment: Nice one, but it doesn't work for more than 2 columns in the order by clause.

Comment: @mik - I can't make it work. Can you save your regex on regex101.com or another online regex tester ? Thanks

Comment: @Yan I have just added test links

Comment: Very smart @mik ! But I am using Java so the regex with embedded perl won't work.

Comment: @Yan Java does not support callouts either, so you will need to stick with repeating the pattern

Answer (score 1):

This will work for up to 3 `upper(...)` calls in an `order by`:

```
(order by (?:(?!upper).)*)(?:upper(\(.*?\)))?((?:(?!upper).)*)(?:upper(\(.*?\)))?((?:(?!upper).)*)(?:upper(\(.*?\)))?((?:(?!upper).)*)
```

Replace matches with:

```
$1$2$3$4$5$6$7
```

It works for no occurrences of `upper()` too.

If you find you need more captures, repeat the last pair of capture groups and add two more backreferences to the replacement.

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/DxkNOkh9SD).

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be very hard with only one regex.

---

Here is a solution for php:

```
$sql = <<<EOD
select upper(a.col1), b.col1
from a join
     b
     on a.q = b.q
order by upper(a.col1), upper(b.col1)
EOD;

$sql = preg_replace_callback('/(?=order by )(.*$)/', 
        function ($m) {
            return preg_replace('/\bupper\b/', ' ', $m[1]);
        },
        $sql
       ); 
echo $sql,"\n";
```

**Output:**

```
select upper(a.col1), b.col1
from a join
     b
     on a.q = b.q
order by  (a.col1),  (b.col1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Based on your reply to my query above, this is how I interpret the question :

There is an SQL query with a fairly standard syntax so that it should ideally run in any database - in particular - mssql, oracle, db2 and h2.

However in this particular case the query has certain syntax which runs ok in mssql and oracle but not db2 and h2,

As such, you want a regular-expression to remove the offending part of the query - which is in the order-by clause for the two target databases where it does not work.

Approach 1 :

First point is that I think a better approach to fixing this would be to simply have the application be aware of the set of databases and have it send a query-identifier and then have the query tailored for the specific database.

This approach will also ensure that the resulting loss of functionality - a result ordered by upper-case can be handled in the application layer for the scenarios where it uses the database which does not support it.

Perferably, use prepared-statements (if the language used by the application supports it or if you can build a layer-specifically for database access which is what apparently you are doing - since you seem to have a point where you are intercepting the incoming query).

Using prepared-statement helps with sql-injection as well as query-optimization.

Approach 2:

If the above is strictly not feasible and you still want to go with reg-exp, then you could split the query into two sections : 
a) before and including order-by 
b) after order-by 
and replace all occurrences of 'upper' with empty string in the section after order-by.

You can then concatenate the first section before (and including) order-by  and the final section with the 'upper' keyword replaced to get back the desired query.

You can also try reversing the query and then search for the first occurrence of  `yb[\s]+redro`, get the index, extract the sub-string, and replace all occurrences of `)[\s]+reppu` with `)` and then reverse the string back and concatenate again.